# How to clear / maintain a django-sentry database?

Tags: django, sentry, data-cleaning

I am using django-sentry to track errors in a website. My problem is that the database has grown too big. The 'message' table and the 'groupedmessage' are related

Is there any way to clear older entries and specific messages or to add the sentry tables to the admin of django?

Comment: AFAIK, db is not recommended to use as a storage for Sentryy in production. Anyway, you can write a management command to delete old resolved messages.

Comment: Thanks ilvar. Yes, I need to review my Sentry implementation. I finally used the console to delete old messages as you suggested.

Comment: also, go ask #sentry at irc.freenode.org? sounds like a pretty standard issue

Answer (score 51):

Use the cleanup command. Two parameters are available:

- days (default: 30) - indicates how old the object must be for it to be cleaned up
- project - indicates which project to delete from since you can have many configured in a single sentry server (default: all)

Use it as such (`--config` now dropped):

```
# sentry --config=sentry.conf.py cleanup --days 360
sentry cleanup --days 360
```

**OR** with an optional project parameter, it must be an integer:

```
# sentry --config=sentry.conf.py cleanup --days 360 --project 1
sentry cleanup --days 360 --project 1
```

I also was able to use the django ORM to do this manually, before discovering the cleanup command:

```
#$source bin/activate
#$sentry --config=sentry.conf.py shell
from sentry.models import Event, Alert
Event.objects.all().count()
Alert.objects.all().count()
```

Check out the sentry models to query other objects. From here you can use the django ORM commands like .save(), .remove()  etc.. on the objects. Check out the available sentry models [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/tree/master/src/sentry/models).  This approach is a bit more flexible if you need the granularity, i.e. modifying objects.  One thing that the cleanup command lacks is telling you how many objects it deleted, it dumps the deleted objects to the screen instead.

My cleanup script looks like this and I run it @monthly using cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
cd /var/web/sentry
source bin/activate
# exec sentry --config=sentry.conf.py cleanup --days 360 #--project 1
# UPDATE: You can now drop the --config param
exec sentry cleanup --days 360
```

Comment: Also, remember to run the command frequently.  Because it uses the Django ORM extensively, it can take a **very** long run the first time if the Database is big.

Comment: As of "some time ago" the config path should be used, not a specific file. Eg: sentry --config=/etc/sentry cleanup --days 360

Answer (score 15):

This is how you perform a cleanup using a dockerized Sentry instance with a default `docker-compose.yml` from the [official guide](https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/docker/):

```
$ # Go to a directory containing the docker-compose.yml:
$ cd sentry-config  
$ docker-compose run --rm worker cleanup --days 90
```

Consider reading help:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm worker help
$ docker-compose run --rm worker cleanup --help
```

Use cron to perform the cleanup regularly. Run `crontab -e` and add there the following line:

```
0 3 * * *  cd sentry-config && docker-compose run --rm worker cleanup --days 30
```

---

**Don't forget to reclaim the disk space** by running `VACUUM FULL {{relation_name}};` inside a Postgres container:

```
$ docker exec -it {{postgres_container_id} /bin/bash
$ psql -U postgres
postgres=# VACUUM FULL public.nodestore_node;    
postgres=# VACUUM FULL {{ any large relation }};
postgres=# VACUUM FULL public.sentry_eventtag;
```

You can run `VACUUM FULL;` without specifying a relation, but this will lock the whole database. So I recommend vacuuming relations one-by-one. [This is how you can find the size of your biggest relations.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)

Answer (score 7):

There is a [cleanup](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli/index.html#cleanup) command. Unfortunately, it's behavior seems undocumented, but the [code comments](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/master/src/sentry/management/commands/cleanup.py) are pretty informative.

Answer (score 2):

To follow on from radtek's helpful answer, if you only want to remove particular errors, the easiest way I've found is to call delete on the `Group` object:

```py
from sentry.models import Group
Group.objects.filter(culprit__contains='[SEARCH TERM]').delete()
```

Where `[SEARCH TERM]` is some text that appears within the error messages you want to remove.

Comment: Actually, if you use cleanup, it performs all trim operations based on your configuration.